# How to hide HTML Controls when form loads in MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

So I am creating MVC project using razor view engine. I have a textbox and a radiobutton. I want to hide text box on form load and show it only on clicking radiobutton. I can achieve later part using jquery.

How can I hide the textbox when view loads? I know in webforms you can do it using eventhandler or by setting Visibility=false.

Here is my [sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Iwii.png)

Comment: You should post your code, not an image of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use jQuery to hide it in the first place as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#element").hide();
});
```